# Evaluating trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Let 
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^{3027} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2018})$$
$$B = \sum_{i=1}^{3027} \cos(\frac{\pi i}{2018})$$

Evaluate 
$$A(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2018}) + B(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2018}))$$

Dividing the summation into 3 parts,
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^{1008} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2018}) +\sum_{i=1010}^{2017} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2018}) +\sum_{i=2018}^{3026} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2018}) + \sin(\frac{1009\pi}{2018}) +\sin(\frac{2018\pi}{2018}) +\sin(\frac{3027\pi}{2018})$$

Using Trig properties, we have 
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^{1008} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2018})$$

Doing the same logic for B

$$B = \sum_{i=1}^{1008} \cos(\frac{\pi i}{2018}) - 1$$
which is
$$B = -\sum_{i=1}^{1008} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2018})-1$$

After this, I  cannot find a solution for the remaining expression

Comment: There are no "$i$"s in the summations defining $A$ and $B$. Also, there's a close-parenthesis missing in the target expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the question to

$$A - \cos(\pi/2018)\sin(\pi/2018)-...-\cos(\pi/2018)\sin(3027\pi/2018)+ \sin(\pi/2018)\cos(\pi/2018)+...+\sin(\pi/2018)\cos(3027\pi/2018)$$

$$=A+(\sin(-\pi/2018)+...+\sin(-3026\pi/2018))$$

$$=\sin(3027\pi/2018) = \sin(3π/2)=-1$$ 
(we used $\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(A)\sin(B)$)